# How to create a smooth CATransition effect

Tags: iphone, uiview

The CATransition what i have implemented works really fine but not smooth, i could see the previous uiview screens during the transition, I am just doing this,

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.1];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[objView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView"];
```

For moving forward and for moving back wards,

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.1];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[objRemovableView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView"];
```

The effect of sliding is not smooth, is there any other way we can do this which works very smooth?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Enough frames cannot be made for such short duration.

Comment: that is just an example..please help increasing the time frame and explain the efficiency please

Answer (score 0):

try to a bit increase the duration of animation. now it is 0.1 sec.